# Can we print out only the values of the documents that are present in the collection using python?

Tags: pymongo-3.x

```
output:
{u'country': u'USA', u'age': 35.0, u'_id': ObjectId('5c481307c45c2d388de3b4ba'), u'id': 11.0, u'name': u'Sachin'}
{u'country': u'India', u'age': 33.0, u'_id': ObjectId('5c481307c45c2d388de3b4bb'), u'id': 12.0, u'name': u'Rahul'}
{u'country': u'China', u'age': 36.0, u'_id': ObjectId('5c481307c45c2d388de3b4bc'), u'id': 13.0, u'name': u'Yadav'}
{u'country': u'UK', u'age': 32.0, u'_id': ObjectId('5c481307c45c2d388de3b4bd'), u'id': 14.0, u'name': u'Jadhav'}
{u'country': u'Japan', u'age': 30.0, u'_id': ObjectId('5c481307c45c2d388de3b4be'), u'id': 15.0, u'name': u'Rohit'}
{u'country': u'Germany', u'age': u'45', u'_id': ObjectId('5c4aa2f0f2f8ba463102fd76'), u'id': u'80', u'name': u'Rahul'}


x = list(coll.find())
for row in x:
    print(row)
```

I expect the output to contain only values that is the fields id,name,age,country should not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I've currently have the same question. As far as I've seen during debuging, the data is pulled from db during the for each print loop. So I made a detour that I copy the data to a list/dictionary and try to pull the data form that.

Please note that I'm new to MongoDB and Python, so their might be a better solution...